# How to check if user's Google Drive has enough space using Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api, capacity

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive using [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

I wanted to know if there is an API method to check if the user's drive has enough capacity to hold the file. If yes, can you please point me to where I should search, if not what is the best way to handle this?

**P.S.:** Please assume that I know the size of the file to upload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[About.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) will tell you user's quota and usage. You can calculate user's free space based on this information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `quotaBytesTotal` and `quotaBytesUsedAggregate` were exactly what I was looking for!